# How to evaluate this integral without numerical methods?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, digamma-function

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{\cos\left(x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

I tried it with Trapezoidal and Simpson's got the correct answer
[which matches with Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+0+to+pi%2F3+e%5E(x)%2Fcos(x)) but how to find that form with hypergeometric and polygamma function ?.

Comment: By writing $\cos x$ as $\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ and by applying a bit of complex analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform this into a form suitable for the hypergeometric function by choosing $x=\ln t$. We then find,

$$
dx=dt/t\\
e^x=t\\
\cos x=\frac{t^i+t^{-i}}{2}\\
\int\frac{e^x}{\cos x}\,dx=2\int \frac{dt}{t^i+t^{-i}}
$$

WolframAlpha gives

$$
2\int \frac{dt}{t^i+t^{-i}}=(1-i)t^{1+i}\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1-i}{2},1;\frac{3-i}{2};-t^{2i} \right)\color{gray}{+const}
$$

Compare that with this, also from WolframAlpha,

$$
\int\frac{e^x}{\cos x}\,dx=(1-i)e^{(1+i)x}\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1-i}{2},1;\frac{3-i}{2};e^{-2ix} \right)\color{gray}{+const}
$$

You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: thanks i got your solution, but from where those di-gamma functions will arise ?

Comment: It must have something to do with a *simplification* (?!) of the the hypergeometric function at one of the limits. However, the only one I have found in a cursory search is $$_2F_1(1,a;a+1;-1)=2a\left[\psi(\frac{a+1}{2})-\psi(\frac{a}{2})\right]$$. Good luck with that!

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer since the result just came out from a CAS.*

$$\int_{0}^{a}\frac{e^x}{\cos x}\,dx=-\frac{1}{2} i \left((2+2 i) e^{(1+i) a} \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2},1;\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i}{2};-e^{2 i
   a}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{i}{4}\right)+\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i}{4}\right)\right)$$ provided that $(2 \Re(a)+\pi \geq 0\land 2 \Re(a)\leq \pi )\lor a\notin \mathbb{R}$